# Extracting .xcarchive files

Tags: xcode, xcarchive

How do you (batch) extract the contents of many .xcarchive files?

The story:

*I have a crash log from a semi-unknown build, this build would match a dSYM. I have lots of dSYMs from all the builds I have. I need to match the crash log versus the dSYM. The process is detailed here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12337755/129202
I have many .xcarchive files with dSYMs, I need to extract the dsym files from the .xcarchive files before I can get their contents. Doing `mdls *.dSYM` while they are still inside an .xcarchive does not give valid output.
I could use Finder to extract the dSYM files but as I have a lot of builds, this is a very tedious task and this leads me to the question, how do you (batch) extract the contents of many .xcarchive files?*

Answer (score 2):

I found out a workaround that does not need extraction of the xcarchives. Run this line instead:

`mdls -name com_apple_xcode_dsym_uuids -raw *.xcarchive`

This will get the UUIDs printed without extraction.
More details here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16875869/129202

Technically this does not answer the question how to extract xcarchives but it does get the UUID out of the dSYM inside an xcarchive which was my case.

Comment: You should be able to find every .dSYM with mdfind com_apple_xcode_dsym_uuids=*

Comment: where to run this line? in which scope im not getting any results